# Golang end goroutine inside for loop with wait time

Tags: algorithm, go, parallel-processing, channel, goroutine

I do have a goroutine which should iterate through a nested array. After each element of the array the `for loop` should wait a time and then iterate to the next element.

The goroutine should stop immediately if a boolean value is passed to a chan given to that goroutine with a select statement. Immediately means to stop the for loop for the nested array and to stop the wait / duration time to process the next element.

At the moment I do have something like the following:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type listEntry struct {
    text     string
    duration time.Duration
}

func timeTrack(start time.Time, name string) {
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Printf("%s took %s\n", name, elapsed)
}

func main() {
    defer timeTrack(time.Now(), "move")
    fmt.Println("-- START --")
    var list [2][10]*listEntry

    var sublist [10]*listEntry
    sublist[0] = &listEntry{"0.0.", time.Duration(2 * time.Second)}
    sublist[1] = &listEntry{"0.1.", time.Duration(3 * time.Second)}
    sublist[2] = &listEntry{"0.2.", time.Duration(4 * time.Second)}
    sublist[3] = &listEntry{"0.3.", time.Duration(9 * time.Second)}
    sublist[4] = &listEntry{"0.4.", time.Duration(32 * time.Second)}
    sublist[5] = &listEntry{"0.5.", time.Duration(21 * time.Second)}
    sublist[6] = &listEntry{"0.6.", time.Duration(19 * time.Second)}
    sublist[7] = &listEntry{"0.7.", time.Duration(11 * time.Second)}
    sublist[8] = &listEntry{"0.8.", time.Duration(9 * time.Second)}
    sublist[9] = &listEntry{"0.9.", time.Duration(6 * time.Second)}

    list[0] = sublist

    var sublist2 [10]*listEntry
    sublist2[0] = &listEntry{"1.0.", time.Duration(2 * time.Second)}
    sublist2[1] = &listEntry{"1.1.", time.Duration(20 * time.Second)}
    sublist2[2] = &listEntry{"1.2.", time.Duration(12 * time.Second)}
    sublist2[3] = &listEntry{"1.3.", time.Duration(9 * time.Second)}
    sublist2[4] = &listEntry{"1.4.", time.Duration(32 * time.Second)}
    sublist2[5] = &listEntry{"1.5.", time.Duration(21 * time.Second)}
    sublist2[6] = &listEntry{"1.6.", time.Duration(19 * time.Second)}
    sublist2[7] = &listEntry{"1.7.", time.Duration(11 * time.Second)}
    sublist2[8] = &listEntry{"1.8.", time.Duration(9 * time.Second)}
    sublist2[9] = &listEntry{"1.9.", time.Duration(6 * time.Second)}

    list[1] = sublist2

    finish := make(chan bool)
    go move(list, finish)
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("-> FINISH CHAN")
    // finish <- true
    close(finish)
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("-- FINISHED --")
}

func move(list [2][10]*listEntry, finish chan bool) {
    for index := 0; index < len(list); index++ {
        fmt.Printf("List: %d\n", index)
        for sublistIndex := 0; sublistIndex < len(list[index]); sublistIndex++ {
            fmt.Printf("Sublist: %d.%d - %v\n", index, sublistIndex, list[index][sublistIndex].duration)
            select {
            case <-finish:
                fmt.Println("move: finish 2")
                return
            case <-time.After(list[index][sublistIndex].duration):
                continue
            }
            // time.Sleep(list[index][sublistIndex].duration)
        }
    }
}
```

Link to Go Playground: [Go Playground Example of the code](https://play.golang.org/p/A_ud-phWXpm)

The ouput is as follows:

```sh
-- START --
Go ...
List: 0
Sublist: 0.0 - 2s
Sublist: 0.1 - 3s
Sublist: 0.2 - 4s
Sublist: 0.3 - 9s
-> FINISH CHAN
move: finish 2
-- FINISHED --
move took 11.0005366s
```

So the execution time is mostly as expected from the time.Wait in the main thread. Great!

But the implementation doesn't look very nice. Guys, do you have a nice idea to structure the code in a more elegant way? Is the first `for loop` and the first select statement even necessary?

Comment: Removing the outer `for` loop would change the behavior - with the outer loop, it will keep re-iterating over the array each time it finishes, and without it, it will return after iterating the array once. Which is the desired behavior?

Comment: Hi, thanks! I think removing the outer loop is the expected behaviour. I've updated the question witt that. But even with only the inner loop it doesn't look nice. What do you think

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't look nice"? What exactly are you looking to solve/improve?

Comment: A more elegant solution. Doesn't feel like the implementation is "best practice" for handling such a use case.

Comment: In what way? It seems basically fine. "More elegant" and "best practice" are still pretty vague and completely opinion-based. What exactly do you see as the problem? What are you looking to improve?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Sync.waitgroup instead of time.Sleep.
Updated code - https://play.golang.org/p/WG-RgqtxO_2